# Registry Monitoring Program on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

Is there an application that watches the registry in real time, and tell me which registry keys got modified when I install a program?

This is useful as I don't want my program, downloaded from the Internet, simply change crucial registry and in the worse case, render my OS unusable.

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool called [regmon](http://download.cnet.com/RegMon/3000-2094_4-10020841.html). It's pretty good for what you are trying to do.

You can also use its spin off called [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor).

Comment: Yes! The Sysinternals tools are the way to go!  Regmon has actually been [retired](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sysinternals/archive/2009/09/18/filemon-and-regmon-retired-newsid-end-of-life.aspx) and replaced by [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), which is a much more flexible and powerful tool.